# Cron job on google compute engine debian linux is failing silently

Tags: php, debian, cron

I'm trying to get my cron jobs to output errors if the cron job fails. I've created a command that will purposefully fail to try and test this, like so:

```
* * * * * php /var/some/nonexistent/script.php >> cronLog.log
```

I don't want to mess with using an MTA since Google Compute Engine blocks all outgoing SMTP requests to port 25, but I can't see anything in cronLog.log. I have the permissions set up correctly, and I can write to cronLog.log no problem when a php script executes successfully. So if the output is being piped successfully to cronLog.log during a successful cron job, why does it just disappear if the command fails? There is nothing in syslog either. Where does my error output go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing stderr which is where the error messages are output. Try

```
 * * * * * php /var/some/nonexistent/script.php >> cronLog.log 2>&1
```

the `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout which is itself redirected to cronLog.log.